# How do I add text to the beginning of a file in Bash?

Tags: bash

Hi I want to prepend text to a file.  For example I want to add tasks to the beginning of a todo.txt file.  I am aware of `echo 'task goes here' >> todo.txt` but that adds the line to the end of the file (not what I want).

Comment: There if no efficient way to do that for large files: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file

Comment: @ould you take a look at this method https://superuser.com/a/1352628/11116

Answer (score 570, accepted):

**Linux :**

```
echo 'task goes here' | cat - todo.txt > temp && mv temp todo.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '1s/^/task goes here\n/' todo.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '1itask goes here' todo.txt
```

**Mac os x :**

```
sed -i '.bak' '1s/^/task goes here\'$'\n/g' todo.txt
```

or

```
echo -e "task goes here\n$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

or

```
echo 'task goes here' | cat - todo.txt > temp && mv temp todo.txt
```

Comment: the first one works great!  would you mind explaining the logic?  im not particularly sure how to interpret the syntax.

Comment: @user8347: Pipe (`|`) the message (`echo '...'`) to `cat` which uses `-` (standard input) as the first file and `todo.txt` as the second. `cat` conCATenates multiple files. Send the output (`>`) to a file named `temp`. If there are no errors (`&&`) from `cat` then rename (`mv`) the `temp` file back to the original file (`todo.txt`).

Comment: cat could be a problem if cat encounters \n

Comment: @itaifrenkel: In what way?

Comment: Instead of printing \n it may print a newline. Happened to me. Used the sed version just fine instead

Comment: @itaifrenkel: I'd have to see what you did, but if `cat` receives a literal backslash n, it won't convert it to a newline. Something else must have done that. Instead of `cat`, try piping into `hexdump -C` to see if you're actually sending backslash and n or if it's a newline. You could also try `cat -e` to show line endings.

Comment: Using 2 and 3 (3 seems simpler to me) allows you to prepend text to *many* files at once.

Comment: cat can be freely used to concatenate binaries. Note how `split` and `join` do entirely different things; `cat` is the companion to `split`, not `join`. And that means, if your `cat` messed up `\n` your implementation is horribly broken.

Comment: Using the third option, I got the task in the file every other line....so I guess it put it on the first line, but didn't do so well for the rest of the file for my use case.

Comment: @onaclov2000: The second `sed` command in my answer says to insert a line of text before line 1. I'd have to see the command you used to know why it inserted it on every other line. You probably omitted the address (`1`).

Comment: I didn't know about this possible syntax in sed's last example, can someone tell me what is the name of this type of syntax so I can search more about it?

Comment: @Kira: The `1` means do the next command only on line one of the file and the `i` command is insert. Look in the man page under the "Addresses" section and in the "Zero- or One- address commands" section.

Comment: The echo line works perfect for DD-WRT firmware for a script I run.  Using sed and putting in the \t for a tab, puts just a t then the next part.  Where the echo line actually puts the tab in instead of the t.  Thank you!

Comment: @Terrance: If your `sed` command looks something like this (inserting a leading tab): `'1i\tSome Text'`, you may need to double the backslash. Otherwise, your dialect of `sed` may not recognize `\t` as tab.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Unfortunately the `sed` doesn't recognize the `\t` as tab.  I forgot to say that I had to do it as `echo -e` to make it work with the tab.

Comment: The `sed` versions don't seem to work on an empty file.

Comment: For what it's worth the cat version is around 3 times faster than the sed ones. At least on the test in did on a ~4GB file.

Comment: Is this also Sh compatible?

Answer (score 108):

A simpler option in my opinion is :

```
echo -e "task goes here\n$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

This works because the command inside of `$(...)` is executed before `todo.txt` is overwritten with `> todo.txt`

While the other answers work fine, I find this much easier to remember because I use echo and cat every day.

**EDIT:** This solution is a very bad idea if there are any backslashes in `todo.txt`, because thanks to the `-e` flag echo will interpret them. Another, far easier way to get newlines into the preface string is...

```
echo "task goes here
$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

...simply to use newlines. Sure, it isn't a one-liner anymore, but realistically it wasn't a one-liner before, either. If you're doing this inside a script, and are worried about indenting (e.g. you're executing this inside a function) there are a few workarounds to make this still fit nicely, including but not limited to:

```
echo 'task goes here'$'\n'"$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

Also, if you care about whether a newline gets added to the end of `todo.txt`, don't use these. Well, except the second-to-last one. That doesn't mess with the end.

Comment: I don't get $(...) executed at all.

Comment: That might work better (or at all) with double quotes instead of single…

Comment: Won't the `-e` also convert escape sequences inside todo.txt?

Comment: Workarounds yield --> cat: <destination filename>: input file is output file ...

Comment: printf would be a lot more consistent across platforms and should generally work more smoothly than echo -e

Comment: Warning: The last one overwrites each file with the echo (or printf) statement.

Comment: I'm not sure this works with large files, bash string size is probably limited to a few MB.

Comment: Warning: replaces occurrences of '\n' with actual newlines

Comment: a little warning here: it can be dangerous to read and directly overwrite a file this way... for one thing, what if the commands happen to operate like this: read position 10000000 to 10100000 and write to the file, but now that position 10000000 is already of the new file? Even if that won't happen, what if the file system becomes full during this, so the new file is being written, but disk full, and fail, and now where is that old file for you to redo this operation when you clean up some disk space? You may lose this file or (part of it)

Answer (score 38):

The [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) have a nice tool called `sponge`:

```
echo "task goes here" | cat - todo.txt | sponge todo.txt
```

It'll "soak up" STDIN and then write to the file, which means you don't have to worry about temporary files and moving them around.

You can get `moreutils` with many Linux distros, through `apt-get install moreutils`, or on OS X using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), with `brew install moreutils`.

Comment: I would go for `(echo 'ble'; cat todo.txt)` :-)

Comment: I would use `tee` instead of sponge which come by default on most distro

    `echo "task goes here" | cat - todo.txt | tee todo.txt`

Comment: The `tee` example is not correct https://askubuntu.com/a/752451

Comment: @stevenpenny Good point. Now I remember why I didn't suggest it originally. I came back to this answer not noticing that the output file name was the same as the input, which is why you need sponge to buffer it all before writing it back out.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the POSIX tool `ex`:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
1 insert
Sunday
.
xit
eof
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new, temporary file.

```
echo "new task" > new_todo.txt
cat todo.txt >> new_todo.txt
rm todo.txt
mv new_todo.txt todo.txt
```

You might also use `sed` or `awk`. But basically the same thing happens.

Comment: Say you're out of disk space so that `new_todo.txt` gets written only partially. Your solution appears to lose the original file.

Comment: Who runs out of disk space? ;-) It's just a simple example.

Comment: @Keith Someone working on a VM who didn't expect to need a particularly large virtual drive. Or someone moving a large file. In any case, the real argument against this is directory permissions; if you don't have permission to create new files in the given directory, the only command that will successfully execute in your script is the `rm` of the original file.

Answer (score 5):

If the text file is small enough to fit in memory, you don't have to create a temporary file to replace it with. You can load it all into memory and write it back out to the file.

```
echo "$(echo 'task goes here' | cat - todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

It's impossible to add lines to the beginning of the file without over writing the whole file.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious question: *Where's the character limit of shell variables?*

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's only limited by the amount of memory available. I've filled up variables well over 100MB into memory. `text=$(cat file)`. Be careful to only use text though, because shell variables aren't binary clean http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/058

Answer (score 3):

You cannot insert content at the beginning of a file. The only thing you can do is either replace existing content or append bytes after the current end of file.

Any solution to your question then requires a temporary file (or buffer) to be created (on memory or on disk) which will eventually overwrite the original file.

Beware of not losing data by preserving the original file while creating the new one, should the file system happen to be full during the process. eg:

```
cat <(echo task go there) todo.txt > todo.txt.new && mv todo.txt.new todo.txt
```

Comment: Downvoters are welcome to explain their motivation. None of the remaining answers, including the accepted one, do contradict anything in my reply.

Comment: This is difficult to parse as the < ... > look like brackets, which I assume they are not. A space between the < and the ( might help?

Comment: This is not working for me. `echo HOME=\"/g/Users/timregan/\" | cat - 'F:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile'` works but `cat <echo HOME=\"/g/Users/timregan/\" 'F:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile'` gives the error "echo: No such file or directory"

Comment: @dumbledad You are overthinking my reply. There is nothing for you to parse in it. A space between the `<` and the `(` would break the syntax.  Try `cat <(echo HOME=\"/g/Users/timregan/\") 'F:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile'`

Answer (score 3):

**Final answer**

```
cat <<< "prepended text
$(cat test.txt)" > test.txt
```

**Context**

I wasn't too satisfied with the answers as they felt like too much typing. I liked John Alberts his answer but couldn't stand to type `-e`. Unfortunately, I accidentally read over John Alberts his `echo` 2 liner as well (significantly reducing the value of this answer and me 30 minutes playing around, but oh well, it happens).

In any case, I was focused on finding something that meant you only needed to type the filename and text you want to prepend.

Moreover, I was searching for something that looked aesthetically intuitive. With that I mean: the preprend needs to physically show, even if it'd be an illusion it'd have the effect of a mnemonic.

So I tried an approach with herestrings since in the right context they reduce cognitive strain (i.e. typing `<` 3 times doesn't require too much thinking power).

I created a file `test.txt` with the word `"monkeys"`.

And I typed:

```
cat <<< "prepend
> $(< test.txt)"
```

Output:

```
prepend
monkeys
```

A bit of clarification:

You need to manually press `enter` yourself.

On the second line the `>` is from the shell itself, you don't need to type that.

Notes:

(1) What I couldn't manage was a one liner. There seems to be no herestring combination in which I could use `$()` and `\n`. Which is why you need to press the newline manually yourself.

(2) `$(< test.txt)` has the same effect as `$(cat test.txt)`. The [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) states:

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent
>   but faster `$(< file)`.

So you could also do:

```
cat <<< "prepend
> $(cat test.txt)"
```

More typing, but I admit a bit less cognitive strain since `cat` is being typed twice and is more well-known than the trick of the Bash Reference Manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tee`:

```
echo 'task goes here' | cat - todo.txt | tee todo.txt
```

Comment: No you cannot http://askubuntu.com/a/752451

Answer (score 0):

**GitBash** + **Windows10** + **Multline**:

Here is a version that lets you use **multi-line strings**.

```
##############################################
## This section for demo purpose only,      ##
## So you can save entire file as           ##
## whatever.sh and run it.                  ##
##                                          ##
##############################################
> MY_TARGET_FILE.txt ##Make Or Clear File
echo "[STARTER_CONTENT]" >> MY_TARGET_FILE.txt
##############################################

## Below is main code:

##################################################
TARGET_FILE_VARIABLE="MY_TARGET_FILE.txt"
ADD_TO_HEAD_VARIABLE=$(cat << "HEREDOC_HEAD_TEXT"
//|  +-------------------------------------+   |//
//|  |                                     |   |//
//|  |     MESSAGE_FOR_HEAD_OF_FILE        |   |//
//|  |                                     |   |//
//|  +-------------------------------------+   |//
HEREDOC_HEAD_TEXT
)
##################################################
TAR=$TARGET_FILE_VARIABLE                       ##
TEX=$ADD_TO_HEAD_VARIABLE                       ##
echo "$TEX" | cat - $TAR > TEMP && mv TEMP $TAR ##
##################################################

## Expected contents of MY_TARGET_FILE.txt :
## //|  +-------------------------------------+   |//
## //|  |                                     |   |//
## //|  |     MESSAGE_FOR_HEAD_OF_FILE        |   |//
## //|  |                                     |   |//
## //|  +-------------------------------------+   |//
## [STARTER_CONTENT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, in two commands, is easier to understand. Say that we want to prepend to `hello.c` from `hello.h`.

```
$ cat hello.c >> hello.h
$ mv hello.h hello.c
```

Before:

```
% cat hello.c 
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
% cat hello.h 
#include <stdio.h
```

After:

```
% cat hello.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```