# How to prepend contents of a file to another

Tags: bash, cat, echo

This question relates to the already asked question [How to add text to beginning of file](https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The answer suggested by Dennis Williamson does the job:

`echo 'task goes here' | cat - todo.txt > temp && mv temp todo.txt`

In the above, the string `task goes here` is added to the start of the file.

If the string `task goes here` is in a file called `myfile.txt`, then how should i change the command? `echo 'myfile.txt'...` OR `echo myfile.txt...` do not do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cat myfile.txt todo.txt > temp && mv temp todo.txt
```

`cat` con"cat"enates several files. In the original solution, the first file
was `-`, which means "standard input", i.e., whatever is piped into the `cat` command. Here you have already two named files, namely `myfile.txt` and `todo.txt`, so you can just use them as arguments for `cat`.